# sanityinc-tomorrow-eighties theme fails to show dired mode colors

Tags: dired, themes, colors

I have the theme `sanityinc-tomorrow-eighties` enabled using

`(load-theme 'sanityinc-tomorrow-eighties t)`.

I love this theme but my dired buffers do not show colors. I have installed and enabled `dired+` package that automatically enables colored `dired` buffers. I know that this theme is the culprit because when I change themes the desired colored `dired` buffer appear.

How can I get `dired` buffers to show colors with this theme enabled?

**Edit**.

When I tried `C-u C-x =` it directs me to the following.

`State : THEMED.
   Face used for directory names.
Lisp expression: ((t
  (:inherit
   (diredfl-dir-name))))`

But I don't have a palette of colors to choose from. Not really know how to edit this.

Comment: With the theme active, put the cursor where the color is wrong or missing, and use `C-u C-x =`. The `*Help*` output should tell you what face(s) are used at that position. Then try customizing that face. But you might need to dig into the theme code to prevent it from using that face completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `sanityinc-tomorrow-night`, but instead of using `dired+` I use [diredfl](https://github.com/purcell/diredfl) like this:

```lisp
(use-package diredfl                    ; Add colours to Dired
  :ensure t
  :config (diredfl-global-mode))
```

From `diredfl` README:

> This is adapted from the extra font lock rules provided by Drew Adams'
>   dired+ package, but published via a modern means, and with support for
>   older Emacsen removed.

Comment: Awesome. That works. Just what I needed.